# Confusion regarding stack growth on x86_64 Linux

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, stack, x86-64

I'm trying to fully understand the stack growth mechanism on function calls and I feel a bit confused. In order to better understand I wrote the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void callee(uint32_t* p)
{
    uint32_t tmp = 9;
    printf("callee - tmp is located at address location:%p and p is:%p \n", &tmp, p);
}

void caller()
{
    uint32_t tmp1 = 12;
    printf("caller - address of tmp1:%p \n", &tmp1);
    calle(&tmp1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    caller();
    return 0;
}
```

And using a **online assembler** converter I got the following assembly output (I left only the code of the `callee` function):

```
.LC0:
    .string "callee - tmp is located at address location:%p and p is:%p \n"
calle:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32 // command 1
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 9 // command 2
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    lea     rax, [rbp-4]
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    nop
    leave
    ret
```

As I understand, taking into account **commands 1 & 2** (noted above), the stack indeed grows down towards lower addresses, and a (sample) output of the compiled code, when I compile it using the command `gcc myProg.c -o prog`, is as follows:

> caller - address of tmp1:0x7ffe423e8ed4
>
> callee - tmp is located at address location:0x7ffe423e8eb4 and p is:0x7ffe423e8ed4

Where it can be seen, that indeed, the local variable allocated within the `callee` function is located in a lower memory address than the local variable within the `caller` function.So far so good.

**Yet**, when I compile the program with the `-O2` option (i.e.: `gcc -O2 myProg.c -o prog`) , a (sample) output of the compiled code is something as follows:

> caller - address of tmp1:**0x7fff0d5bfa90**
>
> callee - tmp is located at address location:**0x7fff0d5bfa94** and p is:**0x7fff0d5bfa90**

Which, this time, depicts that the local variable allocated within the `callee` stack frame is located in a higher memory address than the local variable within the `caller` function.

So my question is - the `-O2` optimization option optimizes "up to" a situation where the stack growth mechanism actually changes or am I missing here something... ?

`gcc` version: 7.3

architecture: x86_64

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.

Appreciate your clarifications.

Guy.

Comment: well, technically speaking, the C doesn't even require the local variables to end up in the stack area at all... it's the most logical implementation, but not required, so any of your assumptions about stack deducted from addresses of local variables are "working" only for particular target platform and compiler version+options, it's not C feature, but particular implementation feature. Actually the whole "stack" thing is not known to C, so as long as you want to stay in C and have portable source, you should avoid these implementation details. (of course understanding implementation helps)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-O2` inlines functions, at which point the compiler is free to do stack allocation however it wants.

Address comparison between separate objects (like `tmp` and `tmp1`) is technically undefined behaviour in C, so **any kind of `>` or `<` relationship between addresses based on function nesting is *not* an observable side-effect that optimization needs to preserve when following the as-if rule**.  Compilers don't even try to do so when inlining functions.

> [ISO C11 draft n1548](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf#page=113), §6.5.8 Relational operators
>
> 5)  When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the
>   address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the
>   same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they
>   compare equal. **If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object**,
>   pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members
>   declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript
>   values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript
>   values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the
>   expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the
>   last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than
>   P. **In all other cases, the behavior is undefined**

Converting addresses to integers like `uintptr_t`, or printing them out and comparing in your head, is not UB, but the results are still not guaranteed based on anything.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `printf` call from `calle` got optimized into `caller` function, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/y2N1GG).

Assembly output for gcc 7.3 `-O2` :

```
.LC0:
        .string "calle - tmp is located at address location:%p and p is:%p \n"
calle:
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     rdx, rdi
        xor     eax, eax
        lea     rsi, [rsp+12]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 9
        call    printf
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
.LC1:
        .string "caller - address of tmp1:%p \n"
caller:
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        xor     eax, eax
        lea     rsi, [rsp+8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+8], 12
        call    printf
        lea     rdx, [rsp+8]
        lea     rsi, [rsp+12]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 9
        call    printf
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        xor     eax, eax
        call    caller
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

As you can see the `calle` function was inlined into `caller`, thus `caller` function calls `printf` two times, first with LC1 string, then with LC0 string. First time it prints the address of `rsp+8` which is `tmp1`, the second time with `rsp+12` which is `tmp2`. The gcc is free to chose the order of variables it chooses.

You can put `__attribute__((__noinline__))` attribute to `calle` to "fix" this, but... you shouldn't expect variables addresses to have any order at all (except when you can, like arrays and structures).

P.S. Calling `"%p"` printf modifier not with a `void*` pointer is technically undefined behaviour, so you should cast printf arg to `void*` before printing. `printf("caller - address of tmp1:%p \n", (void*)&tmp1);`